# How to capture picture or generate thumbnail from video in python django restframework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Actually, I am trying to capture to make a thumbnail from an uploaded video in python Django. And then I have to save this thumbnail in a separate model field for later use.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='post_videos/%Y/%m', null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images/%Y/%m', null=True)
```

I just want to upload a video, capture a thumbnail at any timestamp and then save it to the thumbnail field. Please, Let me know if anyone can help me out. I tried using FFmpeg and moviepy but unable to resolve the issue. waiting for help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ffmpeg. What issue did you run into?

```
import subprocess
video_input_path = post_object.video.path
# or whatever the path of the uploaded video file is
img_output_path = 'path/to/image'
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', video_input_path, '-ss', '00:00:00.000', '-vframes', '1', img_output_path])
```

And then you can assign it to the thumbnail field

Comment: `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.post_image:
            picture = Image.open(self.post_image.path)
            picture.save(self.post_image.path, optimize=True, quality=10)` i want to owerrite save method for thumbnail. I don't how to do that for video generated thumbnail.

Comment: Use [django-imagekit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit) it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @kinshukdua does django-imagkit keep the ratio of the image when using processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)] ?

Comment: that's not working. that imagekit is for making a thumbnail from a picture. but we have to capture frame from uploaded video and then save it to a directory. for capturing images we've to open the video and then capture the frame within the given video duration. Let me know if anyone can help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.save()
    video_path = instance.file.path
    clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
    thumbnail_filename = f"thumbnail_{instance.id}.jpg"
    thumbnail_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'files', 'thumbnails', thumbnail_filename)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(thumbnail_path), exist_ok=True)
    thumbnail = clip.get_frame(1) 
    thumbnail_image = Image.fromarray(thumbnail)
    thumbnail_image.save(thumbnail_path)
    instance.thumbnail = os.path.join('files', 'thumbnails', thumbnail_filename)
    instance.save()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).